# Javascript/Rails authorization fetch headers

Tags: javascript, authentication, token, fetch

So I'm developing React/Redux SPA app and I want to have an authorization working. I have Rails backend with devise_token_auth gem working and (in React app) I need to save a token responded to me by the backend. No tokens are available through `response.headers` though. Why? CORS are set up propertly on the backend side so I'm sure that's not the problem. Take a look at the code and screenshot:

```
let config = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(creds) // { email: 'asd@example.org', password: 'asdasdasd' }
}

return dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestLogin(creds))
  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in', config)
    .then((response => {
      response.headers.forEach((el) => console.log(el))
    }))
}
```

console.log:

[image: console.log from code above]

proof that browser sees headers:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend just returning the token in the sign_in response body instead of trying to add it to the header. There is no benefit from a security standpoint.

Comment: @BlairAnderson i use devise-token-auth and i can't find an configuration option for that (i don't want to monkeypatch). still, that is very strange to not see all the headers in JS and I'd fix that first for the good sake. But thanks for replay :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed. the issue was on the backend side. i had this in my rack-cors initializer:

```
headers: :any,                                                                                                         
methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
```

changed to this:

```
headers: :any,
expose: ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
```

everything is working now :)
got it when looking through devise_token_auth's source code.